# How to parse a date with spaces?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have this date: `" 1 21998"`, which is Feb, 1st 1998. It's a little bit malformed as there should be zeros instead of spaces, but it's in some text files I have to process. I don't know how to parse it with C#. Could anyone give me a clue?

I've tried the following but get no result:

```
DateTime date;
string input = " 1 21998";

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "ddMMyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine("1: " + date);
}
else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "ddMMyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine("2: " + date);
}
else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "dMyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine("3: " + date);
}
else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "dMyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine("4: " + date);
}
else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, " d Myyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine("5: " + date);
}
else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, " d Myyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine("6: " + date);
}

if (DateTime.TryParse(input, out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine("7: " + date);
}
else if (DateTime.TryParse(input, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine("8: " + date);
}
```

Comment: You can process the string before you parse it. Take 4 chars from the right and then split the left part with space you will have the parts you need. Then you can either concat those parts in a parseable way or convert them to integers and directly create a `DateTime`

Comment: Can you replace the whitespaces to zero before you try to parse them?

Comment: Can you show examples for 2 symbol month and days? If they do not contain spaces - then replacing whitespace with zeroes and using `"ddMMyyyy"` should do the trick.

Comment: Of course I can replace the spaces first. But I was wondering if there's no way to do it with `TryParseExact()` or `TryParse()` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `" d Myyyy"` is correct for the input `" 1 21998"`; it's just that the parser throws its hands in the air for a variable-length concatenation.

I haven't looked at the source, but I guess the parser first tries to break up the string into individual components matching the pattern, before trying to parse the actual values.

So the parser wouldn't know whether the first *one* or the first *two* digits of your five-digit string "21998" belong to the month, even though there is no 21st month and you specified that the year will have four digits.

It works if you prepend a zero or one to the month:

- `" 1 021998"` -> 02/01/1998
- `" 1 121998"` -> 12/01/1998

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) say, under "Remarks":

> If format is a custom format pattern that does not include date or time separators (such as "yyyyMMddHHmm"), use the invariant culture for the provider parameter and the widest form of each custom format specifier. For example, if you want to specify hours in the format pattern, specify the wider form, "HH", instead of the narrower form, "H".

Not sure what that is about, but `" dd MMyyyy"` nor `"ddMMyyyy"` work for the original input. I guess they meant that you should *write* dates using their widest forms when not writing separators.

The problem isn't the spaces; it's lack thereof. These work:

- `"dMyyyy"`, `" 1 2 1998"` (with `DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces`)
- `"ddMMyyyy"`, `"01021998"` (with `DateTimeStyles.None`)
- `" dd MM yyyy"`, `" 01 02 1998"` (with `DateTimeStyles.None`)

Given your input is fixed-length, the pattern will break again if the month is > 9 (`" 1102021"` won't parse either for the same reasons as before).

The easiest solution would be to parse it manually by breaking up the strings, parsing them as ints and passing them to a `new DateTime(year, month, day)`.

```
var day = int.Parse(input[0..2], NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite);
var month = int.Parse(input[2..4], NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite);
var year = int.Parse(input[4..8], NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite);

var date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. Breaking the date-field into three parts if it cannot be parsed is what I already did. So I will keep my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not turn all the spaces in the input into 0's and then it should be a valid date format?

```
input.Replace(" ", "0");
```

Might also want to put /'s after the 2nd and 4th index too.

```
input.Insert(2, "/");
```